# PROLOG - Change elements in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to change elements in a list, I have the following code:

```
change_aux(_,_,[],[]).
change_aux(X,Y,[X|T],[Y|S]):-!,change_aux(X,Y,T,S).
change_aux(X,Y,[Z|T],[Z|S]):-change_aux(X,Y,T,S).

flatten2([], []) :- !.
flatten2([L|Ls], FlatL) :-
    !,
    flatten2(L, NewL),
    flatten2(Ls, NewLs),
    append(NewL, NewLs, FlatL).
flatten2(L, [L]).

change(X,Y,[X1|Y1],[X2,Y2]):-
    flatten([X1|Y1],L),
    change_aux(X,Y,L,[X2|Y2]).
```

Input: `change(2,5,[1,[2,[3,2],1]],R)`.

Print: `R = [1, [5, 3, 5, 1]]` .

But I need R to be printed like this: `R = [1,[5,[3,5],1]]`

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in the code above like  in definition `change(X,Y,[X1|Y1],[X2,Y2]):-` I don't think that the output list should always consists of two elements. Besides that the change_aux predicate needs some work since now it's just traversing the list and not building the nested output list. You could try something that would build recursively the nested levels of the list like:

```
change(_,_,[],[]).
change(X,Y,[H|T],[H|T1]):- \+is_list(H),dif(H,X),change(X,Y,T,T1).
change(X,Y,[X|T],[Y|T1]):- change(X,Y,T,T1).
change(X,Y,[H|T],[L|T1]):- is_list(H),change(X,Y,H,L),change(X,Y,T,T1).
```

Note that in the above predicate there is no need to use `flatten/2` predicate since we take advantage of the nested levels of input list to build output list.

Example:

```
?- change(2,5,[1,[2,[3,2],1]],R).
R = [1, [5, [3, 5], 1]] ;
false.
```

Comment: Perfect! I understand now... Thank you!

Comment: glad that helped!!